# Flask Edit Profile Page Not Rendering

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a Flask Application and for whatever reason, I cant get my Edit-Profile form to load. I don't get an error, I just get an empty screen. Any help here would be immensely appreciated.

Heres my models.py:

```
class User(db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    #confirmation_code = db.Column(db.Sting(200))

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id')) 
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic') 
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', 
    lazy='dynamic') 

    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text())
    member_since = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    avatar_hash = db.Column(db.String(32))
```

Here's my views.py

```
@server.route('/edit-profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_profile():
    form = EditProfileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.name = form.name.data
        current_user.location = form.location.data
        current_user.about_me = form.about_me.data
        db.session.add(user)
        flash('Your Profile Has Been Updated')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user.username))
    form.name.data = current_user.name
    form.location.data = current_user.location
    form.about_me.data = current_user.about_me
    return render_template('edit_profile.html', form=form)
```

And here's my Forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(Form): 
    name = StringField('Real Name', validators=[Length(0, 64)])
    location = StringField('Location', validators=[Length(0, 64)])
    about_me = TextAreaField('About Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    #photo = FileField()
```

Edited - Here's edit_profile.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %} 

{% block title %} Deplorable Snowflake- Edit Profile {% endblock %}

{% block page_content %} 

<div>

<h1> Edit Your Profile </h1>

{{wtf.quick_form(form)}}

</div>



{% endblock %}
```

Thanks again in advance

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing `edit_profile.html`.

Comment: @Fian sorry about that - here it is